# assign php output (ajax) to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my first time using javascript please be respectful. I have a form which is submitting data via ajax. Everything works as intended, however I'm trying to assign what recd.php is echoing to recresponse so the correct error code is displayed in an alert. Any help or examples would be appreciated.

**Form:**

```
<form action="recd.php" method="post" id="GAMEAPPID">
<input type="text" name="GAMEAPPID" id="GAMEAPPID" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("#GAMEAPPID").on("submit", function(e){

    // prevent native form submission here
    e.preventDefault();

    // now do whatever you want here
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr("method"), // <-- get method of form
        url: $(this).attr("action"), // <-- get action of form
        data: $(this).serialize(), // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#result").html("");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);

     if(recresponse === "0") {
alert("Incomplete.");
  }

     if(recresponse === "1") {
alert("Duplicate.");
  }

     if(recresponse === "2") {
alert("Failed");
  }

    if(recresponse === "3") {
alert("Thanks");
  }

    document.getElementById("GAMEAPPID").reset();
    refreshMyDiv();




        }
    });
   });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is `recresponse` ? Is it defined anywhere ?

Comment: recresponse is the number echo'd by recd.php it isn't defined for example on submit: recd.php echos 0 1 2 3

Comment: Rename recresponse to data, secondly don't use same ID in form and element (bad practice)

Comment: let me try that thanks

Comment: Response is received as argument of `success` handler..In your case, `data` is response from server..

Comment: no alert pops up if i rename all the recresponse's to data

Comment: Try `alert(data);`

Comment: thanks that helped a ton. seems theres more than just the number in there

Comment: We need to see the php script to determine what is actually being sent back to the JavaScript call.

Comment: hey jeff seems like they helped resolve my issue ill make a last reply in a minute thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to answer. in your "recd.php", you should assign the recresponse to a element like `<input type="hidden" id="myRS" value="<?= $myRS ?>" />`

and then you can access the element in your javascript.

Comment: sorry i accidentally omitted this input when cleaning up my question thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks. I am happy with receiving my first tick on your post. :)